# How does a CIDR range specify the IP addresses within it?

Tags: ip, bitmask, cidr

I have read a number of articles and posts about VPCs, CIDR and subnets but I still find the explanations confusing.
Many of the explanation can't help avoiding using domain knowledge or technical terms.
Is there a more basic explanation for someone who gets basic programming, binary, etc. ?
I am wondering in the context of aws VPCs.

Answer (score 5):

How does a CIDR represent an IP address range ?

Start with an IP address:

```
xx.xx.xx.xx
```

This actually represents **Four 8 bit numbers**.
With a dot between each.
As they are 8 bit numbers, they can be from 0 up to 255 (decimal).
They are frequently shown as `xx.xx.xx.xx` because this is referring to them as four 8 bit numbers, shown in [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) (base 16) format.  In 'hex' format `255` (decimal) is written as  `FF`

So the numbers range from `00.00.00.00` to `FF.FF.FF.FF` - in hex
Or `0.0.0.0` to `255.255.255.255` in decimal

For the purpose of considering how many IP 'addresses' this represents - i.e. how many individual IP addresses - you can do 255 * 255 * 255 * 255 which is 4228250625.  Because you have used FOUR 8 bit numbers you multiply them together to produce that number.  It is 2*32.  You'll notice that the 32 is 8 + 8 + 8 + 8 and that is the four 8 bit numbers in `xx.xx.xx.xx`

OK, so now to CIDR.  Where all the above 8 bit, base 16 and hexadecimal / binary information will be useful...
So a CIDR is a range of IP's.
For example you might want a range of 10.0.0.0 to 10.0.0.255 which is 255 IPs.  You can write this using the above format, i.e. 10.0.0.1 to 10.0.0.255 but there is another way to do it and that is by using CIDR - Classless Inter Domain Routing.  Lets stick with calling it CIDR.  so with CIDR you refer to a range using a format like this:

> 10.0.0.0/24

and that means the range `10.0.0.0` to `10.0.0.255`, i.e. `255` numbers.

So has does that work ? !

ok, first we are given which might be thought of as the starting address of the range - `10.0.0.1`, although this is actually a bit misleading because the CIDR number is going to affect it.
So lets go piece by piece.

#### The "/24" refers to the number of bits on the *left* that stay fixed.

This is probably the hardest but also most essential piece to understand.

So taking "24".  this means (conveniently with 24!) that you consider the **first** 24 bits, i.e. the `10.0.0` to be **fixed** (see [bitmask](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_(computing))).  Only the last 8 bits of the xx.xx.xx.xx can change, i.e. you have a range and it is from `10.0.0.0` to `10.0.0.255`

Here's one of the most surprising facts initially:

#### The **larger** the CIDR number, e.g. `/28`, `/30`, etc. the **smaller** the available range of IP addresses !!!

This is because the `/nn` CIDR number refers to how many bits are FIXED and the more bits are FIXED the less bits are can be *changed* to produce a range, and thus the *smaller* the range.  This is why with /32 there is NO range because you are saying all 4 xx.xx.xx.xx numbers (8 + 8 + 8 + 8 = 32) are fixed.  Whereas with 10.0.0.1/24 you can have from `10.0.0.0` to `10.0.0.255` because the 24 indicates the first three numbers (again 8 + 8 + 8 bits = first 3 numbers) are **fixed**) and only the last 8 bits, i.e the '`zz`' in `xx.aa.bb.zz` can change for this range.  One more example: 10.0.0.0/16 (so first two 8 bit numbers are fixed) means 10.0.0.0 to 10.0.255.255.

Because this behavior is due to a netmask `10.0.0.0/24`, which produces the range `10.0.0.0` to `10.0.0.255` would produce the same result if you supplied `10.0.0.0/24`, `10.0.0.73/24` or `10.0.99.17/24`

See an online converter at https://ipaddressguide.com/cidr

With aws you are given 10.0.0.0/16 as your VPC which means the "10.0" part will stay fixed.  so that means if you want a subnet within that you want something smaller such as `10.0.0.0/24` or `10.0.1.0/24` of which you will be able to have many.

The next thing that may be a bit unexpected is that within a VPC subnets must not overlap.  However you *can* have multiple VPCs using that range.  The second piece takes some explanation:

There are three IP ranges set aside as PRIVATE so they are never used 'publicly'.  These lets each network use those as 'internal' addresses.  They are the, probably familiar

```
10.0.0.0 to 10.255.255.255
172.16.0.0 to 172.31.255.255
192.168.0.0 to 192.168.255.255
```

So when you get a VPC that uses a 10.0.0.0/16 range you are getting ONE private network within "a' network. As if you were 'one' user at home using your single network.  You can create another VPC because that uses another network (like having a second router in your house) and on that network 10.0.0.0./16 is available.
You currently have a default limit of 5 VPCs *per region*.  As each VPC is using private subnet ranges, they can actually be the same for different ones as well as different, however if you ever want the VPCs to be able to communicate with each other (using VPC peering) this will be a problem because the subnets can't overlap when you do that (otherwise the router wouldn't know which subnet to pick for a given address that exists in both).
[image]

---

Any other corrections **I am happy to incorporate** wiki-style. I am not defending my knowledge, just trying to share what I think I know and help others understand this confusing concept!

Here's how you do it in aws:

[image]
[image]
[image]

### Nope! You have to avoid within 10.0 - the existing public subet !

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

## Result

[image]